how to laravel join json format
sql query like this, My query works like this but how can I get a simpler output?;
$order_divided_piece = OrderDividedPiece::select('collection_color_size_barcode.*', 'order_divided_piece.*', 'collection_divided_order.plm_id', 'collection_divided_order.warehouse_id')
            ->Join('collection_divided_order', 'collection_divided_order.id', '=', 'order_divided_piece.divided_order_id')
            ->Join('collection_color_size_barcode', 'collection_color_size_barcode.id', '=', 'order_divided_piece.collection_color_size_barcode_id')
            ->where('collection_divided_order.order_id', $request->order_id)
            ->get();

I came out like this
{
"id": 1,
"collection_color_id": 345,
"size": "36",
"barcode": "8683048325537",
"divided_order_id": 2,
"collection_color_size_barcode_id": 1106,
"piece": 54,
"plm_id": 123456,
"warehouse_id": 1,
"order_id": 3828
},
{
"id": 2,
"collection_color_id": 345,
"size": "38",
"barcode": "8683048325544",
"divided_order_id": 2,
"collection_color_size_barcode_id": 1107,
"piece": 54,
"plm_id": 123456,
"warehouse_id": 1,
"order_id": 3828
},
{
"id": 3,
"collection_color_id": 345,
"size": "34",
"barcode": "8683048325575",
"divided_order_id": 3,
"collection_color_size_barcode_id": 1105,
"piece": 24,
"plm_id": 321321,
"warehouse_id": 4,
"order_id": 3828
},
{
"id": 4,
"collection_color_id": 345,
"size": "40",
"barcode": "8683048325551",
"divided_order_id": 3,
"collection_color_size_barcode_id": 1108,
"piece": 55,
"plm_id": 321321,
"warehouse_id": 4,
"order_id": 3828
},
{
"id": 5,
"collection_color_id": 345,
"size": "42",
"barcode": "8683048325568",
"divided_order_id": 3,
"collection_color_size_barcode_id": 1109,
"piece": 43,
"plm_id": 321321,
"warehouse_id": 4,
"order_id": 3828
}

How can I adjust my output by grouping like this.
My sql query comes with repetitive data in json format. How can I extract them more regularly and simply as follows?
Thank you in advance for your help.
[
  {
    "collection_color_id": 345,
    "order_id": 3828,



    "depo": {
      "warehouse_id": 1,
      "plm_id": 123456,
      "divided_order_id": 2,



      "beden": {
        "id": 1,
        "size": "36",
        "barcode": "8683048325537",
        "collection_color_size_barcode_id": 1106,
        "piece": 54,
        
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "size": "38",
        "barcode": "8683048325544",
        "collection_color_size_barcode_id": 1107,
        "piece": 54,
        
      },
      
    },



    "depo2": {
      "warehouse_id": 4,
      "plm_id": 321321,
      "divided_order_id": 3,



      "beden2": {
        "id": 3,
        "size": "34",
        "barcode": "8683048325575",
        "collection_color_size_barcode_id": 1105,
        "piece": 24,
        
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "size": "40",
        "barcode": "8683048325551",
        "collection_color_size_barcode_id": 1108,
        "piece": 55,
        
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "size": "42",
        "barcode": "8683048325568",
        "collection_color_size_barcode_id": 1109,
        "piece": 43,
        
      }
    }
  }
]


Eloquent API Resources
